# Conditions with common logic: question of style, readability, efficiency, 

Tags: coding-style, conditional-statements, code-coverage, pseudocode

I have conditional logic that requires pre-processing that is common to each of the conditions (instantiating objects, database lookups etc). I can think of 3 possible ways to do this, but each has a flaw:

**Option 1**

```
if A
   prepare processing
   do A logic
else if B
   prepare processing
   do B logic
else if C
   prepare processing
   do C logic
// else do nothing
end
```

The flaw with option 1 is that the expensive code is redundant.

**Option 2**

```
prepare processing  // not necessary unless A, B, or C
if A
   do A logic
else if B
   do B logic
else if C
   do C logic
// else do nothing
end
```

The flaw with option 2 is that the expensive code runs even when neither A, B or C is true

**Option 3**

```
if (A, B, or C)
   prepare processing 
end

if A
   do A logic
else if B
   do B logic
else if C
   do C logic
end
```

The flaw with option 3 is that the conditions for A, B, C are being evaluated twice. The evaluation is also costly.

Now that I think about it, there is a variant of option 3 that I call option 4:

**Option 4**

```
if (A, B, or C)
   prepare processing 
   if A
      set D
   else if B
      set E
   else if C
      set F
   end
end

if D
   do A logic
else if E
   do B logic
else if F
   do C logic
end
```

While this does address the costly evaluations of A, B, and C, it makes the whole thing more ugly and I don't like it.

How would you rank the options, and are there any others that I am not seeing?

Comment: On the whole, the compiler ought to reduce any of these alternatives to something pretty efficient.  So I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: I don't follow how Option 4 avoids the costly evaluations. You still have to do (A, B or C) followed by an A, B or C (i.e. two evaluations).

Answer (score 1):

Can't you do

```
if (A, B, or C)
   prepare processing 
   if A
      do A logic
   else if B
      do B logic
   else if C
      do C logic
end
```

? Maybe I misunderstood.

Edit: zzz, your edits messed me up. If you don't want it to evaluate A,B,C twice then do

```
x = func returnCase() //returns a,b, or c
if x != None
   prepare processing
   do Case
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't this solve the redundancy:

```
if A
   prepareprocessingfunction()
   do A logic
else if B
   prepareprocessingfunction()
   do B logic
else if C
   prepareprocessingfunction()
   do C logic
// else do nothing
end

prepareprocessingfunction() {
   prepare processing
}
```

Comment: never mind, that still evaluates the expensive code 3 times of course